# When I try to run the nextjs project using npm run dev, it sopped automatically

Tags: web, next.js, next.js13

> account@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

then it exits

I got one time a dns because it was running, got the dns error then it stopped.
I also tried to create a new project with the same name, without doing anything to the code, and when I try to run it, it doesn't even say ready started it exits directly.